# Is encryption exposed in pisa at all?

Tags: python, django, pisa

I need to be able to allow a user to save and preview a PDF file, but 
*not* print it.  The reportlab instructions seem pretty 
straightforward, but I didn't see it in the docs for pisa.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Previously I was using POD Appy Framework. It is very ease and clean to handle. You can check the document http://appyframework.org/pod.html